# CNN with imbalanced data stuck with 70% testing accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, resnet, vgg-net, efficientnet

I'm working on image classification task for diabetic retinopathy with fundus image data. There are 5 classes. The data distribution is 1805 images (class 1), 370 images (class 2), 999 images (class 3), 193 images (class 4), 295 images (class 5).
Here are the steps that I have tried to run:

1. Preprocessing (resized 224 * 224)
2. The divide of train and test data is 85% : 15%

```
x_train, xtest, y_train, ytest = train_test_split(
    x_train, y_train, 
    test_size = 0.15, 
    random_state=SEED,
    stratify = y_train
)
```

3. Data agumentation

```
ImageDataGenerator(
        zoom_range=0.15,
        fill_mode='constant',
        cval=0.,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
    )
```

4. Training with the ResNet-50 model and cross-validation

```
def getResNet():
    modelres = ResNet50(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape= (IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_HEIGHT, 3))
    x = modelres.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(5, activation= 'softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs = modelres.input, outputs = x)
    return model

num_folds = 5
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle=True, random_state=2021) 
cvscores = []
fold = 1
for train, val in skf.split(x_train, y_train.argmax(1)):
    print('Fold: ', fold)
    Xtrain = x_train[train]
    Xval = x_train[val]
    Ytrain = y_train[train]
    Yval = y_train[val]
    data_generator = create_datagen().flow(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size=32, seed=2021)

    model = getResNet()
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                   optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), 
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
    with tf.compat.v1.device('/device:GPU:0'):       
          model_train = model.fit(data_generator,
                                   validation_data=(Xval, Yval),
                                   epochs=30, batch_size = 32, verbose=1)
    model_name = 'cnn_keras_aug_Fold_'+str(fold)+'.h5'
    model.save(model_name)
    scores = model.evaluate(xtest, ytest, verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
    fold = fold +1
```

The maximum results I got from this method were training accuracy of 81.2%, validation accuracy of 72.2%, and test accuracy of 70.73%.
Can anyone give me an idea to improve the model so that I can get the test accuracy above 90% as possible?
Later, I will use this model as a pre-trained model to train diabetic retinopathy data as well but from other sources.

BTW, I've tried replacing my preprocessing with this method:

```
def preprocessing(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = crop_image_from_gray(image)
    green = image[:,:,1]
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    cl = clahe.apply(green)
    image[:,:,0] = image[:,:,0]
    image[:,:,2] = image[:,:,2]
    image[:,:,1] = cl
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224,224))
    return image
```

I've also tried to replace my model with VGG16, EfficientNetB0. However, none of that had much effect on my results. I'm still stucked with about 70% accuracy.
Please help me come up with ideas to improve my modeling results. I hope.

Comment: As your dataset is imbalanced, you should give us the accuracy per class, instead of the mean. You will probably notice that some classes have less accuracy than others. The goal is then to improve the results for those ones. For example, you can try to weigth the loss based on the inverse of the classes distribution. You can also try oversampling.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try oversampling my data with augmentation @RémiChauvenne

Answer (score 0):

Your training accuracy is 81.2%. It is generally impossible to have testing accuracy higher that training accuracy, i.e. with current setup you will not achieve 90%.

However, your validation (and also testing) accuracy is about 70-72%. I can suggest that on your small dataset your model is overfitting. So if you add model regularization (e.g. dropout), it is possible that the gap between your training and your validation (and test) will decrease. This way you can improve your validation score.

To further increase the score, you need to check your data manually and try to understand which classes contribute the most to the errors and figure out how those errors can be reduced (e.g. updating your preprocessing pipeline).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try all your suggestions. 
I want to add regularization to the model, but how do I implement it if I use ResNet which is already available in Keras?

Comment: The simplest would be to try a smaller model. Also see this https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-add-regularization-to-keras-pre-trained-models-the-right-way-743776451091